# Updating contents of a jsp page without refreshing

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a jsp page which shows the contents of a table.
While the user views a page the contents of the table changes on a second-by-second basis.
So the user has to refresh the page every time to see fresh and updated contents.
How can i update contents of the jsp page without having to refresh the page.
I wanted a functionality just like in gmail.com where the size of the mailbox just keeps increasing without users refreshing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should look into using Ajax (jQuery is my preferred method).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

This would then hit a controller that would return the data you want without refreshing the page.

So for instance, if you had a login.jsp...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
    Hello please login to this application  
</h1>
<script>

        function login(){
            var username = $("#username").val();
            var password = $("#password").val();

            $.post('login', { username : username , password : password }, function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow');
            } );
        }

</script>
Username : <input id="username" type="text" />
Password : <input id="password" type="password" />
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Click me" onclick="login()" />
<form name="next" action="auth/details" method="get">
    <input name="send" type="submit" value="Go Through"/>
</form>
<div id="results" />
</body>
</html>
```

In your controller, you would then hit the Model, but for simplicity, I've done a very simple example...

```
/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    Util util;

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model, String username, String password) {


        if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("david"))
        {
            model.addAttribute("validUser", "Welcome " + username );

            return "home";
        }
        else
        {
            model.addAttribute("validUser", "Incorrect username and password");
            return "home";
        }

    }

}
```

This would then add a slow scrolling bit of html to the div to say if it's valid, the code for home is below...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="true" %>
<html>
<body>
<P>  ${validUser}. </P>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of a jsp page doing the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can make ajax request and pull the data from server and use java script to render that data on the view

Comment: Can you provide a sample of a jsp page doing the same