# Loading data through Jquery ajax for datagrid?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, datagrid

I have this code snippet(not complete though, ignore the ending script tag) ::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gotoa(){
    var h = $.get("http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp", function(result) {

    });
    alert(result);


var myVar= h;
var storedata={
            identifier:"ID",
            label:"name",
            items: myVar
    };

var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata});
```

The code for GetJson.jsp is ::

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="MyPackage.PopulateTextbox" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<%

String temp1;
PopulateTextbox obj = new PopulateTextbox();
temp1 = obj.method();
%>

<%=temp1 %>

</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

I have a j query get method . And the URL i am passing in it returns me an Json array string. Output of URL ::

```
[{"ID":1,"Names":"Shantanu","Email":"shantanu.tomar@gmail.com"},{"ID":2,"Names":"Mayur","Email":"mayur.sharma@gmail.com"},{"ID":3,"Names":"Rohit"},{"ID":4,"Names":"Jasdeep"},{"ID":5,"Names":"Rakesh","Email":"rakesh.shukla@gmail.com"},{"ID":6,"Names":"Divyanshu"},{"ID":8,"Names":"hello"},{"ID":9,"Names":"fine"},{"ID":10,"Names":"shivani"}]
```

Now i want this output for my Data grid i.e i want that var myVar should get this value and then it will be passed on to dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore. I am unable to do so . Please help ? Thanks.

Comment: I love the questionmark in "please help ?"

Answer (score 0):

The `$.get()` function is a shorthand for an AJAX call using the `$.ajax()` function - and, as everybody knows, the first A in AJAX stands for asynchronous. If you want to execute code using the response of an AJAX call, you need to put that code in the callback function passed to `$.get()`.

It may look something like this (though without the code being complete, I can't say for certain:

```
function gotoa() {
    var store;

    var h = $.get("http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp", function(result) {
        var myVar = result;
        var storedata={
            identifier:"ID",
            label:"name",
            items: myVar
        };

        store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata}); 
            // do whatever with store here, if necessary
    });
}
```

Comment: Have tried it Anthony... But is not working .. See the above post... :(

Answer (score 0):

modify your script tag like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gotoa(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp", function(result) {
        var storedata={
            identifier:"ID",
            label:"name",
            items: result
             };

            var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: storedata});
    });

}
</script>
```

The code for GetJson.jsp is :

```
<%@page contentType="application/json" %>
<%@page import="MyPackage.PopulateTextbox" %>
<%
String temp1;
PopulateTextbox obj = new PopulateTextbox();
temp1 = obj.method();
%>

<%=temp1 %>
```

Now call `gotoa()`
it will initialize the ajax call and get the response in callback function

Comment: I am not getting it ryt Nemoy.. :( its not displaying any error also. But not displaying any result also in data grid. I think items: is not getting the appropriate value. But when i do open the URL i do get the Json array of values which i have given as output in my ques. What may be the reason ? will it make any difference if we change content Type to text/HTML instead of application/json ? thanks.

Comment: alert the response and post it here, or can you expose the link?

Comment: Here's the output whn i open the link http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp and content type text/html: [{"ID":1,"Names":"Shantanu","Email":"shantanu.tomar@gmail.com"},{"ID":2,"Names":"Mayur","Email":"mayur.sharma@gmail.com"},{"ID":3,"Names":"Rohit"},{"ID":4,"Names":"Jasdeep"},{"ID":5,"Names":"Rakesh","Email":"rakesh.shukla@gmail.com"},{"ID":6,"Names":"Divyanshu"},{"ID":8,"Names":"hello"}] Now when content type is application/json i get the same out with all the html tags also body n all, with the output placed outside body tag, where the scriptlet code is placed.

Comment: modify it to 

`$.get("http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp", function(result) {
    alert(result);
    });`
and check whether it is alerting something or not

Comment: Hey nemoy. I am now getting the data. The response alert gives me an output like [Object object][Object object]... so on(the number of values in my database. and content type is application/json. But when i click the URL does not fetch me the new updated values according to changes in the database. But if i run the URL separately in a browser the new values get updated in the result. And then when i click on pane to update the grid i get the updated values. Is it somewhat related to callbacks ?  What may be the reason. please help. Thanks.

Comment: it might be caching, try cache busting

`$.get("http://localhost:8080/2_8_2012/jsp/GetJson.jsp?random=" + new Date().getTime(), function(result) { alert(result); });`

Comment: Okay .. Now i am getting the [Object object][object object]... values according to the number of database values without refreshing the URL separately.. date time thing is working fine. :) Thanks for that. But grid is not updating itself after that. Is there any specific function for grid to be refresh again and display updated data ? thanks a lot for your help nemoy..

Comment: Great, you can use $.ajax with cache: false to avoid caching.

I am not sure about your grid component,

Comment: Nemoy if u can please help me out on this one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716745/refreshing-grid-data-on-click-event  Thanx.. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736725/data-is-not-getting-displayed-in-dojox-data-datagrid-on-click-event

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768294/displaying-data-in-dojogrid-using-dojo-xhrget-method