# How to call javascript at Java Service?

Tags: javascript, java, ionic-framework

I build application on IONIC V1 and make some background service. In service I try call some file from javascript. I have folder structure like this

[image]

Is it possible to call **file.js** at **class.java** ? And How to call file.js at class.java ? If you have some idea please tell me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Obviously you can! One method is by including the path via AJAX call

```
$.get("www/js/file.js", function (response) {

                                                         }, "json");
```

Please do check this:

[how to call a java class method in javascript using ajax ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700055/how-to-call-a-java-class-method-in-javascript-using-ajax)